# Requisição Post funciona no Postman mas não funciona com Script Python

Tags: python, post, script, postman, pagemethods

Estou fazendo um script para renovar links da takeblip, a questão é que os mesmos atributos que uso no postman, coloquei no script, no postman funciona normalmente, só que no script não funciona nem por reza.

O script apresenta o erro 62:

```
'method': 'set', 'status': 'failure', 'reason': {'code': 62, 'description': "There's no processor available for requested resource type"},
```

Segue script:

```
import json
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox
import webbrowser

def renew_url():
    # Obter a URL digitada pelo usuário
    url = url_entry.get()

    # Montar o payload JSON com a URL fornecida
    payload = {'id': '{{$guid}}', 'method': 'set', 'uri': '/refresh-media-uri', 'type': 'text/plain', 'resource': url}
    # Configurar os cabeçalhos
    headers = {
        'authorization': 'a key fornecida',
        'content-type': 'application/json'
        }
    #converte payload para json
    payload_json = json.dumps(payload)
    # Enviar a requisição HTTP POST com os cabeçalhos
    response = requests.post('https://http.msging.net/commands', json=payload_json, headers=headers)
    #print(response)
    print(response.json())
    print(response.content)
    print(response.request)
    print(response.ok)
    # Verificar o código de status da resposta
    if response.status_code == 200:
        messagebox.showinfo('Sucesso', 'A URL foi renovada com sucesso.')
        # Abrir o link renovado no navegador
        webbrowser.open(url)
    else:
        messagebox.showerror('Erro', f'Ocorreu um erro ao renovar a URL. Código de status: {response.status_code}')

# Criar a janela
window = tk.Tk()
window.title('Renovar URL Take Blip')

# Criar a label e a entry para a URL
url_label = tk.Label(window, text='Digite aqui a URL que chegou no seu e-mail:')
url_label.pack()
url_entry = tk.Entry(window, width=50)
url_entry.pack()

# Criar o botão de renovar URL
renew_button = tk.Button(window, text="Renovar", command=renew_url)
renew_button.pack()

# Executar a janela principal
window.mainloop()
```

Agradeço desde já pela ajuda...

Answer (score 0):

#### Problema

O problema pode estar relacionado à forma como você está convertendo o payload JSON para uma string JSON antes de enviar a requisição. No seu código, você está usando `json.dumps(payload)` para converter o payload em JSON. No entanto, quando você chama `requests.post`, você está passando `json=payload_json`, que já é uma string JSON.

#### Correção

Para corrigir isso, você pode remover a linha que converte o payload em JSON usando `json.dumps`. Em vez disso, você pode passar o payload diretamente como um dicionário Python para o parâmetro json em `requests.post`. Dessa forma, o requests irá automaticamente converter o dicionário em uma string JSON corretamente.

#### Código

Aqui está o código atualizado que corrige esse problema:

```
import json
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox
import webbrowser
import requests

def renew_url():
    # Obter a URL digitada pelo usuário
    url = url_entry.get()

    # Montar o payload JSON com a URL fornecida
    payload = {
        'id': '{{$guid}}',
        'method': 'set',
        'uri': '/refresh-media-uri',
        'type': 'text/plain',
        'resource': url
    }

    # Configurar os cabeçalhos
    headers = {
        'authorization': 'a key fornecida',
        'content-type': 'application/json'
    }

    # Enviar a requisição HTTP POST com os cabeçalhos
    response = requests.post('https://http.msging.net/commands', json=payload, headers=headers)

    print(response.json())
    print(response.content)
    print(response.request)
    print(response.ok)

    # Verificar o código de status da resposta
    if response.status_code == 200:
        messagebox.showinfo('Sucesso', 'A URL foi renovada com sucesso.')
        # Abrir o link renovado no navegador
        webbrowser.open(url)
    else:
        messagebox.showerror('Erro', f'Ocorreu um erro ao renovar a URL. Código de status: {response.status_code}')

# Criar a janela
window = tk.Tk()
window.title('Renovar URL Take Blip')

# Criar a label e a entry para a URL
url_label = tk.Label(window, text='Digite aqui a URL que chegou no seu e-mail:')
url_label.pack()
url_entry = tk.Entry(window, width=50)
url_entry.pack()

# Criar o botão de renovar URL
renew_button = tk.Button(window, text="Renovar", command=renew_url)
renew_button.pack()

# Executar a janela principal
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Bom dia!

Cara, fiz a modificação conforme sua orientação, entretanto o erro persiste.
O mais estranho disso tudo é que se eu utilizo o postman, com as mesmas variáveis, funciona normalmente.
Vou continuar pesquisando até conseguir encontrar uma solução pra isso.
Agradeço pela atenção!